# Cannot resolve alias 'Scaffold' because it refers to term 'Invoke-Scaffolder',

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

im trying to run this simple scaffolding command using Scafoold Controller Car in order to do my scaffolding framework up and running. but it give me the below error all the time. Appreciate if you guys can help me to solve this.

Cannot resolve alias 'Scaffold' because it refers to term 'Invoke-Scaffolder', which is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program, or script file. Verify the te
rm and try again.

Note:- I already installed Nuget packager for my vs 2015,and T4scaffolding latest in my Vs2015 Professional .

Thanks